# How many states are examined in the most wins heuristic for tic-tac-toe (9-grid)?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I'm new to AI, and have a hard time to understanding how to count the total states are examined in the most wins heuristic for tic-tac-toe two plys deeper(9-grid)? Need help

Comment: Tic-tac-toe is a pretty small game. Furthermore, at the start of the game, there are may symmetries. For example, there are really only three possible first moves -- the centre (which can be played just one way), the corner and the middle of an edge (which can be played four ways each). So you should be able to answer your question just by drawing out the search tree. (Note that, despite its name, the "most wins" heuristic doesn't require you to play out the game to the end and see who wins.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you for the comment. I did some research and saw some people say there would be 25 examined states in total, is that the final answer?

Comment: I dunno. I explained how to figure it out yourself.